# range-v3: can range::remove be made to work on a view::chunk?

Tags: c++, range-v3

It appears ranges::remove cannot operate on a ranges::views::chunk.

```cpp
#include "range/v3/algorithm/remove.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <range/v3/view/chunk.hpp>
#include <vector>

int main() {

    std::vector<int> v{
        1, 2, 3, 4,
        5, 6, 7, 8, 
        9, 10, 11, 12,
        13, 14, 15, 16
    };

    auto a = ranges::views::chunk(v, 4);
    for (const auto& e: a) std::cout << e[0] << "\n";

    auto it = ranges::remove(a, 9, [](const auto& e) { return e[0]; });

    // expected result  (xx means unspecified)

    // std::vector<int> v{
    //     1, 2, 3, 4,
    //     5, 6, 7, 8, 
    //     13, 14, 15, 16,
    //     xx, xx, xx, xx
    // };

}
```

Errors are "does not satisfy" a chain of concepts: permutable, forward_iterator, etc..

```
      constraints not satisfied [with I = ranges::chunk_view<ranges::ref_view<std::vector<int>>>, S = int, T = (lambda at
      /home/oliver/c/physicssim/app/parremove.cpp:19:36), P = ranges::identity]
        constexpr I RANGES_FUNC(remove)(I first, S last, T const & val, P proj = P{})
                    ^
/home/oliver/c/physicssim/ext/range-v3/include/range/v3/detail/config.hpp:633:27: note: expanded from macro
      'RANGES_FUNC'
#define RANGES_FUNC(NAME) operator() RANGES_FUNC_CONST_ /**/
                          ^
/home/oliver/c/physicssim/ext/range-v3/include/range/v3/algorithm/remove.hpp:42:22: note: because
      'ranges::chunk_view<ranges::ref_view<std::vector<int>>>' does not satisfy 'permutable'
            requires permutable<I> AND sentinel_for<S, I> AND
                     ^
/home/oliver/c/physicssim/ext/range-v3/include/range/v3/detail/prologue.hpp:35:26: note: expanded from macro
      'template'
    template<__VA_ARGS__ CPP_TEMPLATE_AUX_                                      \
                         ^
/home/oliver/c/physicssim/ext/range-v3/include/range/v3/iterator/concepts.hpp:841:9: note: because
      'ranges::chunk_view<ranges::ref_view<std::vector<int>>>' does not satisfy 'forward_iterator'
        forward_iterator<I> &&
        ^
/home/oliver/c/physicssim/ext/range-v3/include/range/v3/iterator/concepts.hpp:371:9: note: because
      'ranges::chunk_view<ranges::ref_view<std::vector<int>>>' does not satisfy 'input_iterator'
        input_iterator<I> &&
        ^
/home/oliver/c/physicssim/ext/range-v3/include/range/v3/iterator/concepts.hpp:363:9: note: because
      'ranges::chunk_view<ranges::ref_view<std::vector<int>>>' does not satisfy 'input_or_output_iterator'
        input_or_output_iterator<I> &&
        ^
....
```

I can see why this would be non-trivial, but think it should be hypothetically possible?

Assuming I am not making an obvious mistake, is there any alternative, or solution/workaround?

Comment: That's not `std-ranges`, it is `range-v3`. Which one exactly do you want to ask about? Also, what do you expect `remove` to do? Because it doesn't erase anything from the container nor does it care about the contents of the chunks. It just reorders elements of the range according to a predicate.

Comment: I used the std-ranges tag because there is not a ranges-v3 tag.. But the title, the #includes and namespaces used should make it obvious that I am referring to ranges-v3. 

views:chunk is going to be in std::ranges in c++23 though.. 

Yes reorder... the next step is erase, but I left it off because that's not the issue.

(edit.. just found the range-v3 tag and ammended)

Basically what I am expecting is to "swap/move 4 elements of v to the end each time the remove condition is met"